# Show / Hide js scripts on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

In index.html I have two .js scripts:

```
<script src="js/one.js"></script>  (16.000 lines)
<script src="js/two.js"></script>  (16.000 lines)
```

I also have two buttons:

```
<button>Show Js One</button>
<button>Show Js Two</button>
```

The first Js has a dropdown menu:
ONE
TWO
THREE

The second Js has a dropdown menu:
FOUR
FIVE
SIX

Onclick button (1 or 2) I want to toggle these lists,
without refreshing or loading the page(I want only one HTML page index.html),

so If I click button1 , show me ONE,TWO,THREE menu , but if I click button2, show me FOUR,FIVE,SIX menu , without load a new page. Is this possible to Show / Hide js scripts on dropdown menu?? Thanks a lot..

Comment: That's a little bit hard.. you should do something like this   
    if (button1 === "one"){
        loadScript("js/one.js")
    } else  if (button2 === "two"){
        loadScript("js/two.js");
    }

Comment: It doesn't work.. any function for that?

Comment: I really don't understand whats the problem here. Have them both included in document. When you press the button 1 call function from one.js when you press button2, call function that is in two.js. Also research export import of functions.

Comment: @ikiK Please try to understand the issue,The thing is that when I click the button <button>Show Js Two</button> ,it doesn't read two.js script and hide one.js script. Dropdown menu  doesn't change the items from ONE-TWO-THREE to FOUR-FIVE-SIX... It doesn't call any function, I need a trick to show & hide scripts js on dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest something like that:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $(document.body).remove('#twojs').append('<script id="twojs" type="text/javascript" src="two.js"></script>');
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="button"></button>

<script id="twojs" src="two.js"></script>
```